# Is there a practical performance difference between casting to primitive type or to its wrapper class?

Tags: java, performance, casting, wrapper, primitive

I have inherited code that has a rather complicated method, whose return type is `Object`.  Depending on the inputs, this method says it is guaranteed to return different types (`Integer`, `String`, `null`, etc.).  I am calling that method in the case where it says it is guaranteed to return an `Integer`.  The following (obviously) does not compile:

```
int result;
result = foo(parameters);
```

The compiler complains about the type mismatch from `Object` to `int`, as well it should.  However, both of the following lines compile:

```
result = (int) foo(parameters);
result = (Integer) foo(parameters);
```

I know that both calls will do what I want them to do.  (For that matter, casting to `short` or `Short` would work.)  My question is this: Is there any **practical difference in implementation** between these two **casting** calls, and is one better than the other with regards to **best practice** or **performance**?  To clarify, I know what the difference is between primitives and wrappers, their memory usage, ability to be `null` and such.  I'm asking only about *casting* from `Object`.

As far as I understand it, both calls will follow the same steps: 1) cast the `Object` to an `Integer` (throwing a `ClassCastException` if necessary), and 2) extract an `int` from that `Integer`.

I apologize if there is a duplicate question out there.  I searched for it, but no question that I found answered the question of casting from `Object` to `int`.

Comment: It's guaranteed to return an `Integer`, but its return type is `Object`?

Comment: Yes.  I know, this may be valid Java, but it's not smart.  As I said, this code is inherited.  I would most certainly not write it that way.

Comment: If `foo()` returns `null` and you cast to `int` a `NullPointerException` will be thrown, that will not be the case when casting to `Integer`, as result will only be `null`. I would go with the `Integer` cast for safety.

Comment: Very good point, thank ye @ortang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practical terms, there is not a huge difference in performance between using `int` and `Integer`. One is technically faster as a primitive, and one has useful class-related methods you can use.

As far as "casting", if `foo()` returns an `Integer` in its method code, there will be 0 performance loss when casting to an `Integer`, since the `Object` returned is already an `Integer`.

If `foo()` returns an `int` there will be a slight cost to cast it to a primitive, but nothing noticeable.

```
public Object fooInt() {
    return 5;
}
public Object fooInteger() {
    return new Integer(5);
}

Integer integerResult = (Integer)fooInteger(); //No cost
integerResult = (Integer)fooInt(); //Small casting cost

int intResult = (int)fooInteger(); //Small casting cost
intResult = (int)fooInt(); //No cost
```

Instead, look at whether or not it would be more useful to use an `int` versus an `Integer` with what you do with the result object later down the line. The cost to cast an `int` to an `Integer` is completely negligible in Java.

Comment: Thoughtful answer, thank you.  The method's documentation guarantees `Integer`, but for all I know, it could really be an `int`.  Down the line, I'll be storing the result into a primitive `int`, so perhaps I should just cast straight to `int`?

Comment: Different programmers have different opinions, but I would say always use a primitive unless you have reason not to. This could be because of Integer class functions you need to use, or Collections of Integers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive values are efficient performance-wise that's the reason why they are made primitive. While in case of object they uses more memory but are very handy in use and provides a very useful APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However, I already know the difference between primitives and wrapper `Object`s.  The question was about _casting_ from an `Object` to an int.  I'll reword the question to make that more clear.